# Dart Async Do Something Else Then Wait

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've read several stackoverflow questions, dart documents, and even watched a video on async and await. I haven't found an answer to my question. I would like to call an async method, execute other code, and then wait on the completion of the async task.

Here's an example of what I'm working with. This is my component

```
Credit credit;
...
Future<Null> getCredit(id) async {
  try {
    credit = await _creditService.getCredit(id);
  }
  catch (e) {
    errorMessage = e.toString();
  }
}
...
void onUpdateCredit(int credit_id) {
  getCredit(credit_id);
  creditDialogTitle = 'Update Credit';
  creditArtistIndex = credit.artist_id;
  instrument = credit.instrument;
  creditNotes = credit.notes;
  creditDialog.open();
}
```

This code crashes because credit is null when an attempt is made to use it. One way around it is combine the two methods:

```
Future<Null> onUpdateCredit(id) async {
  try {
    credit = await _creditService.getCredit(id);
    creditDialogTitle = 'Update Credit';
    creditArtistIndex = credit.artist_id;
    instrument = credit.instrument;
    creditNotes = credit.notes;
    creditDialog.open();
  }
  catch (e) {
    errorMessage = e.toString();
  }
}
```

Nothing is done is parallel and, if I need the credit some where else in my code, I would have to duplicate the try/catch portion of the method. I could also code it like this:

```
void onUpdateCredit(int credit_id) {
  credit = null;
  getCredit(credit_id);
  creditDialogTitle = 'Update Credit';
  while (credit == null) {//wait a period of time}
  creditArtistIndex = credit.artist_id;
  instrument = credit.instrument;
  creditNotes = credit.notes;
  creditDialog.open();
}
```

In other situations, I do something similar to this in my html with *ngIf="var != null" where var is populated by a future.

Is there a better way than using while (credit == null) ? This example only executes one instruction between the request and the completion so is trivial. I'm sure I'll other situations where I have a lot to do in between. I'm also adding the service method:

```
Future<Credit> getCredit(int id) async {
  try {
    String url = "http://catbox.loc/credits/${id.toString()}";
    HttpRequest response = await HttpRequest.request(
        url, requestHeaders: headers);
    Map data = JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    final credit = new Credit.fromJson(data);
    return credit;
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw _handleError(e);
  }
}
```

### Update

Based on @Douglas' answer, this works:

```
Future<Null> onUpdateCredit(id) async {
  Future future = getCredit(id);
  creditDialogTitle = 'Update Credit';
  await future;
  creditArtistIndex = credit.artist_id;
  instrument = credit.instrument;
  creditNotes = credit.notes;
  creditDialog.open();
}
```

I then eliminated the intervening method.

```
Future<Null> onUpdateCredit(id) async {
  try {
    Future<Credit> future =  _creditService.getCredit(id);
    creditDialogTitle = 'Update Credit';
    credit = await future;
    creditArtistIndex = credit.artist_id;
    instrument = credit.instrument;
    creditNotes = credit.notes;
    creditDialog.open();
  }
  catch (e) {
    errorMessage = e.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCredit(credit_id)` does not just kick off an asynchronous call, it also returns a `Future` object - immediately. Store that object in a local variable, and you can use it later to asynchronously execute additional code when it completes.

There are two ways to use that `Future` object. The easier and more fluent way requires that you declare `onUpdateCredit` to be `async`. Inside an `async` function, the line `await futureObject` will cause all code after that line to be executed asynchronously after the `Future` completes. The complete version of `onUpdateCredit` using this technique would look like this:

```
Future<Null> onUpdateCredit(int credit_id) async {
  Future future = getCredit(credit_id);
  creditDialogTitle = 'Update Credit';
  await future;
  creditArtistIndex = credit.artist_id;
  instrument = credit.instrument;
  creditNotes = credit.notes;
  creditDialog.open();
}
```

The other way is to explicitly register the rest of your code as a callback using `.then()`. That would look like this:

```
void onUpdateCredit(int credit_id) {
  Future future = getCredit(credit_id);
  creditDialogTitle = 'Update Credit';
  future.then((_) => {
    creditArtistIndex = credit.artist_id;
    instrument = credit.instrument;
    creditNotes = credit.notes;
    creditDialog.open();
  });
}
```

Note that in either case, if the exception path occurs in `getCredit(id)` you will get errors for `credit` not being set. If you truly want the exception to be swallowed silently, you should have its handler fill in a default value for `credit` so that code that assumes it completed normally will still work.

Also note that your while loop version would fail - Dart, like JavaScript, is not truly multithreaded, and busy waiting like that will block the event loop forever, preventing the code that would set `credit` from ever running.

A short summary of how `async` and `await` work in general:

```
Future someFunc(args) async {
  ...
  return value;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
Future someFunc(args) {
  return new Future(() => {
    ...
    return value;
  }
}
```

The code inside gets executed on a later iteration of the event loop, and the returned future completes either successfully with `value` or exceptionally with anything thrown in that code.

Meanwhile this:

```
try {
  value = await someFutureObject;
  ...more code here...
} catch (e) {
  ...exception handling here...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
someFutureObject.then((value) => {
  ...more code here...
}).catchError((e) => {
  ...exception handling here...
});
```

The most common use case is `someVar = await someAsyncCall();`, but you can save the `Future` itself by omitting `await`, or you can `await` on an arbitrary `Future` object no matter where it comes from.

*However* - and this is what makes `await` and `async` so incredibly convenient - you can have 5 different exit points from the `async` function interspersed with three `await` calls (in the same `async` function) in assorted places inside 13 nested loops, switches, try/catch, and `if` blocks, and Dart will automatically figure out the necessary tree of callbacks to make it all follow the same code path as if all the calls were synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I read several mentions of the return of the future, but no example on how to use it.

Comment: I agree about the while loop when I went to look up an example, they were quite complex. Dart does not have a wait(time).

Comment: So if the try catch in getCredit(id) catches the error, it will set the error message and the processing will continue at await future? If so, would adding a try catch to onUpdateCredit fix the problem? The method _creditService.getCredit also contains a try catch. If I need to add a third one, it seems like it would make sense to get rid of getCredit and call _creditService.getCredit directly.

Comment: @curt The async-compatible non-blocking equivalent of `wait(time)` for Dart is `await Future.delayed(time)`. This will put the rest of the code as a callback on the event loop after the specified time and, as with all uses of the `await` keyword, is only allowed in an `async` function. Adding a try/catch around the `await` in `onUpdateCredit` would help only if you remove the one in `getCredit`, allowing the exception to propagate. You could instead put a null check, but I'd agree `getCredit` isn't adding much value in the code you've shown.

Comment: @curt Also, do you understand the usage of `.then()`, `.catchError()`, etc. on futures? I could explain how `async` and `await` map to the function based equivalents pretty concisely, if you already understand the functional concepts.

Comment: I've used .then or the equivalent in javascript. I implemented the first solution you gave. Thanks for the help. I'll probably end up coding about 50 these calls

Comment: @curt See my edit for an expansion on what `async` and `await` mean in `.then`-like terms, then.